# The way fulltext MATCH() AGAINST() scores are calculated? According to table or just according to given fields?

Tags: mysql

I could not find answer to my question anywhere. I have done a research but without any luck.

Let's say that we query a following statement:

```
SELECT `id`, MATCH(`name`,`content`) AGAINST ('some keywords') AS `score` FROM `pages` WHERE MATCH(`name`,`content`) AGAINST ('some keywords')
```

Is MySQL going to give me a score according for the whole table `pages`, will it scan for all other records there? Or is it going to give me a score just considering a row with columns supplied (`name` and `content`) in our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it uses the keyword frequency in other rows too. Taken from [MySQL Fulltext Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html), the formula is:

> w = (log(dtf)+1)/sumdtf * U/(1+0.0115*U) * log((N-nf)/nf)
>
> Where:
>
> dtf     is the number of times the term appears in the document sumdtf
>   is the sum of (log(dtf)+1)'s for all terms in the same document U
>   is the number of Unique terms in the document N       is the total
>   number of documents nf      is the number of documents that contain
>   the term